# Accessing SegmentedButton Buttons To Change Badges in Sencha

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, badge

I've declared a new Ext.SegmentedButton() called "myseg" with a couple of items... In a another function i want to access the badges of each button in "myseg" and change the values... how do I got about doing that? How can I access the "buttons" collection via "myseg" ?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't fully tested my own anser but I believe it is meant to be done through:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query();
```

This method should return the button components if let's say you do this:

```
var buttons = myseg.query('button); // return an array of components
```

and then loop through....

```
buttons.forEach(function(btn){ btn.setBadge('badgevalue')})
```